# Cakephp Form cannot create file type input

Tags: php, forms, cakephp

my Form is

```
<?php  echo $this->Form->create('User', array('type' => 'file')); ?>
```

.
.
.
.

```
<?php 
echo $this->Form->input('Profile-Picture', array('type' => 'file','name' => 'data[User][profileimg]')); ?>

<?php echo $this->Form->end(('Submit')); ?>
```

On Controller function it display data array like:

```
Array
(
    [User] => Array
        (
            [id] => 22
            [fname] => Mehr
            [lname] => Jamil Rana
            [username] => Mehr Rana
            [email] => mehreen@abc.com
            [password] => 619016456d0023d6a57b3f3551c474bf
            [Retype password] => 
            [term_approved ] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                )

            [profileimg] => thumbthumbnailofslide1.png
        )

)
```

Comment: what is the question ?

Comment: Question is $this->data['User']['profileimg']['name'] always display the first charachter of uploaded file and $_FILE array size is 0

Comment: it should be like this [profileimg] => Array
                (
                    [name] => ...
                    [type] => ..
                    [tmp_name] => /tmp/....
                    [error] => 0
                    [size] => 9925590
                )

Comment: <form action="/styleClub/users/edit/22" id="UserEditForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8"><div style="display:none;"><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT"/></div>

Comment: See my answer I hope it will work for you !

Comment: Of course `...['profileimg']['name']` won't work as `profileimg` is a string. Please update your question (do not put this in the comments) with the exact contents of `$_FILES` and the complete generated form. Also please always mention your exact CakePHP version!

Comment: This `[profileimg] => thumbthumbnailofslide1.png` is the result of having a file input that is not in a multi-part form. BUT: It looks like you're doing things the wrong way round - why are you asking for a field that doesn't exist and forcing the name? You probably want to be doing e.g. :`echo $this->Form->input('profileimg', ['type' => 'file', **'label'** => 'Profile-Picture'])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <?php
 echo $this->Form->create('User',array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data')); 
echo $this->Form->input('profileimg',array('type' => 'file','label'=>'Profile-Picture')); 
 echo $this->Form->end(('Submit'));
```

Answer (score 0):

> Due to the limitations of HTML itself, it is not possible to put default values into input fields of type ‘file’. Each time the form is displayed, the value inside will be empty.

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-file-inputs

Answer (score -1):

When you make a POST request, you have to encode the data that forms the body of the request in some way, for $_FILES you need to add multipart/form-data encoding.

Try this

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('User', array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'));
      echo $this->Form->input('Profile-Picture', array('type' => 'file','name' =>'data[User][profileimg]'));
      echo $this->Form->end(('Submit')); 
 ?>
```

Comment: That's what [**`'type' => 'file'`**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#options-for-create) is there for.

Comment: @ndm your statement is incorrect. The 'type' => 'file' is define what type of input it is. It does not pass the full information of the file through. http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-file-inputs

Comment: @Stosh15 My statement is correct, just follow the link. `type` is an option for `FormHelper::create()`.

Answer (score -1):

use encrypt option for file , and in input tag mention the input is file type.